# What is the word for "understandable by specific group"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Please suggest the word which means "understandable by specific group". I just forgot that.

Comment: Are you looking for "classifiable?" maybe a little more context would help explain which word you seek.

Comment: More context is needed to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are lots of words covering the general concept, but they're usually used by people who are *not* members of the "specific group", so they tend to be pejorative.

**Esoteric** strikes me as somewhat less value-laden than most.

Comment: Esoteric is the word i was looking for :)

Comment: There's also *arcane*, which wouldn't really be pejorative. If someone suggested I had arcane understanding, I would not be offended.

Comment: "Esoteric" implies that it is *only* understandable by a specific group. It may be the answer sought but I don't feel it matches the question that well. To me, "Domain-specific" may be more fitting but Rakesh is happy.

Comment: Depending on context, colloquial could be appropriate.

Comment: *arcane* certainly bucks the trend by normally having *positive* associations for non-group-members - but it's a bit archaic / quaint, and is often used jocularly nowadays.

Answer (score 11):

While not a direct answer to your question, the term **jargon** refers to language (words and phrases) that are common in one specific group but not used that way outside the group.

For example, in medical jargon, a heart attack is called a myocardial infarction.

Comment: I think this may be exactly what the asker wants, he just didn't phrase it particularly clearly.

Comment: @Martha, no it is not *jargon*

Answer (score 1):

An "in-joke" is a term used describe an event that is humourous only to a small group of insiders to whom the full history leading up to the event is known, thereby allowing them to find humour in the situation that would otherwise to an outsider not appear to be humourous.

Answer (score 1):

You *may* be looking for the word **shibboleth**. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth):

> A shibboleth ( /ˈʃɪbəlɛθ/ or /ˈʃɪbələθ/) is any distinguishing practice that is indicative of one's social or regional origin.

It is also used to mean words used by a members of a group to distinguish themselves as members of that group. When used this way, it is being used metaphorically.