# Word that means "private word used by a group"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Here's an example: a group of my friends has a term we invented.  It's a verb that means "to pronounce over-correctly", used of a word borrowed from another language when that word has a common anglicized pronunciation, but the speaker of the word chooses instead to pronounce in the source language.  There may be a standard English word that has this same meaning, but our private word is derived from the name of a person we know who does this often, and so it's sort of an inside joke: "Oh, stop Trauthing, you pompous fool."

The word I'm looking for describes such a private word.  Sort of like a single word in an *idioglossia* but with no surrounding language; the private word stands on its own.  Taking a cue from *neologism* I might coin the word *idiologism* but that word apparently already exists (or so says google) and has a slightly different meaning since it's only used by one person.

Is there a word for a coined, private word, which has a specific meaning only to a certain small group of people?

Comment: inside joke....

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18049/what-is-the-word-for-understandable-by-specific-group

Comment: Jargon is useful for anyone who hears it. Jargoff is specific to your group and not useful to others.

Comment: Shibboleth is exactly the correct answer, good work Ramsay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would call the word itself a *pet term.*  This is an interesting topic, and pet terms are probably common within families and other small, tight-knit groups.

An example of this usage, in a headline from a media analysis website:

> Limbaugh Explains His **Pet Term** "New Castrati": Men Who Are "Bullied By Women And The Power Structure And Liberalism"

Note that this is not the same as a *term of endearment.*

EDIT:  This is not an established linguistic term.  I consulted a few sociolinguistics textbooks and didn’t find any discussion of this kind of ephemeral in-group language.  One place to look would be studies of college slang, like Connie Eble’s *Slang and Sociability.*

*Pet term* is also different from *pet word,* which seems to have a generally accepted meaning:  a word that is frequently used or otherwise favored by an individual person or writer. *Pet words* are already part of the general lexicon, though.  Brad Leithauser has a 2013 New Yorker piece about pet words.  He gives some examples (*sweet* for Shakespeare, *lad* for A.E. Housman) and compares them to stray cats taken in by their users:

> Each of these words presents the critic with a little puzzle of devotion: What was it about this particular package of syllables? Why was this stray cat escorted into the author’s studio and offered a saucer of cream and a plump pillow by the fireplace? It’s not as though the studio were soundproof; during working hours, the author no doubt could hear other strays, seemingly no less deserving, meowing clamorously for admission.

Link: [Pet Words](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/books/2013/09/writers-favorite-words-reflect-their-world-view.html)

So, *pet **term*** (rather than *word*) can convey that it's favored by the in-group, but not established as a true word yet.

Comment: I like this and it sounds pretty close to what I'm looking for.  But I can't seem to find a definition or any other examples besides the one about Limbaugh and "New Castrati".  Do you have any other references?

Comment: @jbyler:  I don't, as I explain in the edit.  What you are looking for is so ephemeral that it seems to have passed under the radar of sociolinguists.

Answer (score 18):

I prefer "***Shibboleth***". It has a great history and REALLY closely matches the context-specific nature of your request.

Per Wikipedia: a word or custom whose variations in pronunciation or style can be used to differentiate members of ingroups from those of outgroups. Within the mindset of the ingroup, a connotation or value judgment of correct/incorrect or superior/inferior can be ascribed to the two variants.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth

Comment: I love *Shibboleth*. I used it a couple of days ago to describe the relationship five year old girls have with the lyrics of *Let It Go*. However, in this particular case I think *argot* is the better answer.

Comment: *Shibboleth* does not fit. It is not about not knowing the word, it is about not being able to learn it. You will never be able to pronounce *[Chuchichäschtli](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuchich%C3%A4schtli)*, so it is a shibboleth. But you can start using a jargon word or an inside joke correctly after hearing it just a single time, thus they are not shibboleths.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: A shibboleth is not unlearnable - it's simply a linguistic (orig.) marker that identifies a particular cultural / ethnic / etc group. For example: "eh" is the quintessential Canadian shibboleth - and easy enough to learn for just about anyone...

Comment: @BenM *Gilead then cut Ephraim off from the fords of the Jordan, and whenever Ephraimite fugitives said, 'Let me cross,' the men of Gilead would ask, 'Are you an Ephraimite?' If he said, 'No,' they then said, 'Very well, say "Shibboleth" (שבלת).' If anyone said, "Sibboleth" (סבלת), **because he could not pronounce it**, then they would seize him and kill him by the fords of the Jordan. Forty-two thousand Ephraimites fell on this occasion. —Judges 12:5–6, NJB*  If it were easily learnable, you'd think some of those forty-two thousand would have learned pretty quickly.

Comment: @BenM But yes, modern usage is more about the marker, and probably doesn't suggest unlearnability.

Comment: I agree with Ben - regardless of etymology, in modern usage, shibboleth doesn't mean that someone *can't* learn (or pronounce) the word, merely that they don't yet *know* (or know how to pronounce) the word.
It it, however, too specific, in that it does refer specifically to a word used by one group to *identify* members of that group, rather than just to any word only members of a group know (it's a subcategory of that.)

Comment: So I like this word, and it's new to me (thanks!), but it doesn't quite fit what I was looking for.  @RegDwigнt has it right.  The type of in-word I'm looking to describe is not used as a marker or differentiator for members of the group.  The word being described is used for its meaning, and for its humor value, not for its value as a group membership marker.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Much better than pet term. Argot is also good though.

Answer (score 13):

I guess [*argot*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/argot):

> special words or expressions used by a profession or group that are difficult for others to understand.

Comment: Argot does not fit. OP specifically mentioned that the word should represent a single word without a surrounding language. Argot is a collection of words or a language. You might say "argot word" but then it is not a single word and there is still a surrounding language.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @ermanen: argot describes a group of words, not a single word.  Plus it seems as though the argot is an important characteristic of the group.  In our case, we don't have a specialized jargon, just this one funky word.  But still, argot is a great word to know, so thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As you are looking for a word that represents a secret word (but not a language or a system), it would be ***codeword (or [code word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/code%20word))***:

> a word or phrase that has a secret meaning or that is used instead of another word or phrase to avoid speaking directly

From [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=code%20word):

> a word or phrase shared by a group which has a special meaning to that group
>
> codewords are often used to hide meaning or intention from anyone not in the group

---

Also, there is ***[cryptonym](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cryptonym)*** but it is usually used for names.

> A word or name that is used secretly to refer to another; a code name or code word.

---

This question deserves a made-up word also: ***idiolexeme***

Though, it is used as a nonce word in a very [few sources](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=D3SaU6zLKsOC8Qf9z4HQCA&gws_rd=ssl#q=idiolexeme&safe=off&tbm=bks) one of which defines as an individual formation.

Answer (score 3):

**[Idiolect](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/33393)**

> is a variety of a language **unique to an individual**. It is manifested
>   by patterns of word selection, vocabulary and word lexicon, grammar,
>   or words, phrases, idioms, or pronunciations that are unique to that
>   individual. Every individual has an idiolect; the grouping of words
>   and phrases is unique, rather than an individual using specific words
>   that nobody else uses. An idiolect can easily evolve into an
>   **[ecolect](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/33394)**—a dialect variant specific to a household.

Comment: Idiolect doesn't fit, since the word is shared among a group, but I think ecolect is pretty closely related.  The only problem is that it describes a whole dialect, not a single one-off word.  If we had a bunch of these words, I think ecolect would be perfect.

Comment: I think you are confusing ecolect(group/household) with idiolect(unique to an individual). The latter of which has been used to identify an individual in a criminal matter (Unabomber).  It was and can be just one word,  or even a style in using that one word, made-up or not.

Answer (score 3):

The following list of [synonyms](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Personification): may be helpful:

*dialect, vernacular, jargon, cant2, argot, lingo, patois.*

> These nouns denote forms of language that vary from the standard.
>
> *Dialect* usually applies to the vocabulary, grammar, and pronunciation characteristic of specific geographic localities or social classes.
>
> *The vernacular* is the informal everyday language spoken by a people.
>
> *Jargon* is specialized language understood only by a particular group, as one sharing an occupation or interest.
>
> *Cant* now usually refers to the specialized vocabulary of a group or trade and is often marked by the use of stock phrases.
>
> *Argot* applies especially to the language of the underworld.
>
> *Lingo* is often applied to language that is unfamiliar or difficult to understand.
>
> *Patois* is sometimes used as a synonym for jargon or cant, but it can also refer to a regional dialect that has no literary tradition.

Comment: jargon should be used

Comment: @vickyace: Jargon would be found in public reference works; it's meaning is standardised, but of interest to (and therefore used by) only few. I gather that the terms OP asks about are _completely meaningless_ outside the group, even for people who would have interest in their meaning; I would not say they qualify as jargon (though it is conceivable that some jargon started out as a kind of secret language).

Answer (score 2):

using an adjective, those are "esoteric" words, which means words intended for or likely to be understood by only a small number of people with a specialized knowledge or interest.

to put it in a noun, I would advise "jargon," as suggested by others or "parlance," which means a particular way of speaking or using words, especially a way common to those with a particular job or interest

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of Orwell, I propose *groupspeak*.

Answer (score -1):

Or maybe **slang**? That is also a kind of internal group speech.